# How to configure husky pre-push hook to run tests

Tags: angular, githooks, husky, git-husky

I am trying to configure husky pre-push hook to run tests before push. Everything looks fine. After run `git push origin` hook is fired and tests are runing. Problem is that when tests are done and even if operation is successed, push is freezed and nothing else happened.

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "pre-commit": "npm run lint",
    "pre-push": "npm run test"
  }
```

**.husky/pre-push**

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npm run pre-push
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default unit tests run in watch mode.
You can override this by doing `ng test --watch=false`

Comment: `--watchAll=false`

Answer (score 1):

If you re using Vitest:

```
yarn vitest --run
```

Comment: https://vitest.dev/guide/cli
"Don't forget that Vitest runs with enabled watch mode by default. If you are using tools like lint-staged, you should also pass --run option, so that command can exit normally."

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

```
npm test -- --watchAll=false
```

I've added that to the pre-commit file that was generated in the husky folder in the repo

This is the whole content of the file

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npm test -- --watchAll=false
```