# jest & pre-push/pre-commit doesn't work correctly

Tags: reactjs, git, next.js, husky

I want to set jest with pre-push(husky) on my project.

When I type **$git push**, the test is working but the push doesn't execute.

Is there anything wrong?

[Version]

"husky: "^7.0.4"

[package.json]

```
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npx lint-staged",
      "pre-push": "npm run test"
    }
  },
```

[.husky/pre-push]

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npm run test
```

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71672335/how-to-configure-husky-pre-push-hook-to-run-tests